# Track width needed higher than pin size

Tags: pcb-design, routing

I'm learning PCB design and more than once I faced this issue. What are the standard practices when the trace width is higher than the pin size? Suppose you are designing a 3A charger with a Micro-USB as input. For example, for [this](https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/629105150521.pdf) connector the 5V pin can take up to 3A. However, the pin width is 0.45mm, which is significantly less than the [recommended](http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/?p=25/) track width when dealing with 3A current.

How to solve this type of incompatibility?

Comment: Just make it as wide as possible as soon as possible?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is that common practice? Will it create a potentially burn of the small bridge?

Comment: No it won't... well if you deal with real currents like 500A in a Car or so, you will do a thermal simulation if needed. but at 3A a limited width for some millimetres will not cause any trouble

Comment: The local area will heat up due to resistance... But being copper, that heat is pulled out to the rest of the trace and dissipated with minimal localized heating.

Answer (score 0):

If your pad Width size is 0.45 mm than , Your track size is 0.45 mm in starting of track width after you spread the size of the track .

so you can match the requirement of the current .